# A tradingview strategy need some fixes - pinescript

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

Dears,

I'm new in Pine Script and looking for your kind help.

I have this beginner-level script that gives (buy signal) when fast MA crossed over slow MA and kept higher than crossing price for 3 days which I call it confirmed bars. It also makes sell signal when slow MA crossed down fast MA with same confirmed bars.

Actually, I don't want to use this sell signal strategy, what I need in below

I need TP signal when X% is generated. For instance, If the buy price is 100, it will be 110 (if x=10%)

the same thing with stop loss when the price is dropped down for a specific percentage.

```
//@version=4
strategy("MovingAvg2Line Cross", overlay=true)
fastLength = input(30)
slowLength = input(50)
confirmBars = input(3)
price = close
mafast = sma(price, fastLength)
maslow = sma(price, slowLength)

bcond = price > mafast
bcount = 0
bcount := bcond ? nz(bcount[1]) + 1 : 0
 
if (crossover(mafast, maslow)) and (bcount == confirmBars)
    strategy.entry("MA2CrossLE", strategy.long, comment="MA2CrossLE")
if (crossunder(mafast, maslow))
    strategy.entry("MA2CrossSE", strategy.short, comment="MA2CrossSE")
//plot(strategy.equity, title="equity", color=color.red, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_areabr)
```

Answer (score 0):

I gave it some visuals also,, change it to your liking. Not sure what time frame you use it hence didnt play with confirmed bars however I believe that condition need to be tweaked

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © SafetyHammer

//@version=4
strategy("MovingAvg2Line Cross", overlay=true)
fastLength = input(30)
slowLength = input(50)
confirmBars = input(3)
bcount_OnOff = input(true, title = "Enable Bar Count Filter")


price = close
mafast = sma(price, fastLength)
maslow = sma(price, slowLength)

bcond = price > mafast
bcount = 0
bcount := bcond ? nz(bcount[1]) + 1 : 0
plot(bcount, title="bcount") // for debug

buy = crossover(mafast, maslow) and (bcount == confirmBars or bcount_OnOff == false)
sell = crossunder(mafast, maslow)

TP1 = input(title="Take Profit 1 %", type=input.float, defval=2.5, step=0.1, group="TP & SL")
TP2 = input(title="Take Profit 2 %", type=input.float, defval=5, step=0.1, group="TP & SL")
TP3 = input(title="Take Profit 3 %", type=input.float, defval=12, step=0.1, group="TP & SL")
stop_percent = input(title="Stop loss %", type=input.float, defval=2.5, step=0.1, group="TP & SL")

TP1_Ratio = input(title="Take Profit 1 Ratio %", type=input.float, defval=25, step=1, group="TP & SL")/100
TP2_Ratio = input(title="Take Profit 2 Ratio %", type=input.float, defval=25, step=1, group="TP & SL")/100


percentAsPoints(pcnt) =>
    strategy.position_size != 0 ? round(pcnt / 100.0 * strategy.position_avg_price / syminfo.mintick) : float(na)

percentAsPrice(pcnt) =>
    strategy.position_size != 0 ? ((pcnt / 100.0) + 1.0) * strategy.position_avg_price : float(na)



TP_1 = strategy.position_avg_price + percentAsPoints(TP1) * syminfo.mintick * strategy.position_size / abs(strategy.position_size)
TP_2 = strategy.position_avg_price + percentAsPoints(TP2) * syminfo.mintick * strategy.position_size / abs(strategy.position_size)
TP_3 = strategy.position_avg_price + percentAsPoints(TP3) * syminfo.mintick * strategy.position_size / abs(strategy.position_size)

Long_SL  = strategy.position_avg_price - percentAsPoints(stop_percent) * syminfo.mintick * strategy.position_size / abs(strategy.position_size)
Short_SL = strategy.position_avg_price - percentAsPoints(stop_percent) * syminfo.mintick * strategy.position_size / abs(strategy.position_size)



current_position_size = abs(strategy.position_size)
initial_position_size = abs(valuewhen(strategy.position_size[1] == 0.0, strategy.position_size, 0))


 
if (buy) 
    strategy.entry(id="Long", long=true)    
 

if (sell) 
    strategy.entry(id="Short", long=false)
    
        

if strategy.position_size > 0 
    strategy.exit("L_TP1", from_entry="Long", qty = initial_position_size * TP1_Ratio, limit = TP_1, stop = Long_SL)
    strategy.exit("L_Tp2", from_entry="Long", qty = initial_position_size * TP2_Ratio, limit = TP_2, stop = Long_SL)
    strategy.exit("L_TP3", from_entry="Long", limit = TP_3, stop = Long_SL) 


if strategy.position_size < 0 
    strategy.exit("S_TP1", from_entry="Short", qty = initial_position_size * TP1_Ratio, limit = TP_1, stop = Short_SL)
    strategy.exit("S_TP2", from_entry="Short", qty = initial_position_size * TP2_Ratio, limit = TP_2, stop = Short_SL)
    strategy.exit("S_TP3", from_entry="Short", limit = TP_3, stop = Short_SL)   


//plot(strategy.equity, title="equity", color=color.red, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_areabr)
plot(mafast, title="mafast", color=color.blue)
plot(maslow, title="mafast", color=color.red)


TP_SL_Lines = input(true, title = "Show Take Profit/SL Lines", group="TP & SL") 

plot(series=strategy.position_size>0 and TP_SL_Lines ? Long_SL  : na , title="SL Long", style=plot.style_linebr, color=color.red)
plot(series=strategy.position_size>0 and TP_SL_Lines  ? strategy.position_avg_price : na , title="Entry Long", style=plot.style_circles, color=color.blue)
plot(series=strategy.position_size>0 and TP_SL_Lines  ? TP_1 : na , title="TP1 Long", style=plot.style_circles, color=color.green)
plot(series=strategy.position_size>0 and TP_SL_Lines  ? TP_2 : na , title="TP2 Long", style=plot.style_circles, color=color.green)
plot(series=strategy.position_size>0 and TP_SL_Lines  ? TP_3 : na , title="TP3 Long", style=plot.style_circles, color=color.green)


plot(series=strategy.position_size<0 and TP_SL_Lines  ? Short_SL  : na , title="SL Short", style=plot.style_linebr, color=color.red)
plot(series=strategy.position_size<0 and TP_SL_Lines  ? strategy.position_avg_price : na , title="Entry Short", style=plot.style_circles, color=color.blue)
plot(series=strategy.position_size<0 and TP_SL_Lines  ? TP_1 : na , title="TP1 Short", style=plot.style_circles, color=color.green)
plot(series=strategy.position_size<0 and TP_SL_Lines  ? TP_2 : na , title="TP2 Short", style=plot.style_circles, color=color.green)
plot(series=strategy.position_size<0 and TP_SL_Lines  ? TP_3 : na , title="TP3 Short", style=plot.style_circles, color=color.green)
```